# How to do a proper search with nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, search

i'm working on a small project that is supposed to allow basic searches of the database.
Currently i'm using nhibernate for the database interaction.
In the database i have 2 tables: Person and Address. The Person table has a many-to-one relationship with Address.

The code i've come up with for doing searches is:

```
public IList<T> GetByParameterList(List<QueryParameter> parameterList)
    {
        if (parameterList == null)
        {
            return GetAll();
        }
        using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<T>();
            foreach (QueryParameter param in parameterList)
            {
                switch (param.Constraint)
                {
                    case ConstraintType.Less:
                        criteria.Add(Expression.Lt(param.ParameterName, param.ParameterValue));
                        break;
                    case ConstraintType.More:
                        criteria.Add(Expression.Gt(param.ParameterName, param.ParameterValue));
                        break;
                    case ConstraintType.LessOrEqual:
                        criteria.Add(Expression.Le(param.ParameterName, param.ParameterValue));
                        break;
                    case ConstraintType.EqualOrMore:
                        criteria.Add(Expression.Ge(param.ParameterName, param.ParameterValue));
                        break;
                    case ConstraintType.Equals:
                        criteria.Add(Expression.Eq(param.ParameterName, param.ParameterValue));
                        break;
                    case ConstraintType.Like:
                        criteria.Add(Expression.Like(param.ParameterName, param.ParameterValue));
                        break;
                }
            }

            try
            {
                IList<T> result = criteria.List<T>();
                return result;
            }
            catch
            {
                //TODO: Implement some exception handling
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

The query parameter is a helper object that i use to create criterias and send it to the dal, it looks like this:

```
public class QueryParameter
{
    public QueryParameter(string ParameterName, Object ParameterValue, ConstraintType constraintType)
    {
        this.ParameterName = ParameterName;
        this.ParameterValue = ParameterValue;
        this.Constraint = constraintType;
    }

    public string ParameterName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Object ParameterValue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ConstraintType Constraint
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Now this works well if i'm doing a search like FirstName = "John" , but not when i try to give a parameter like Street = "Some Street". It seems that nhibernate is looking for a street column in the Person table but not in the Address table.

Any idea on how should i change my code for so i could do a proper search? Tips? Maybe some alternatives?

Disclaimer: i'm kind of a noob so please be gentle ;)
Thanks, Denis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is looking for the Street property in the Person entity (notice ORM language... there are no tables and columns ;-)) because of this line:

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<T>();
```

I assume that your type `T` is Person, and so your criteria assumes that the constraints that you are adding refer to properties in Person.

If you pass in a parameter that you know is a filter on the Address entity, you need to call `CreateAlias(...)` to "join" to the Address.

Comment: The thing is i don't really know what the user is searching for up until i get the search request. I was hoping to make this search generic (for example if i add some new entity to the domain so i don't have to change the code). Is there any way that i could tell nhibernate to make a "cascading" ( i don't know if this the right word) search?

Comment: I don't think NHibernate (or any ORM... but I might be wrong) can do this for you. I suggest you modify your QueryParameter class and GetByParameterList method to support specifying the child entity that the parameter actually exists on (if it doesn't exist on the primary entity).

Comment: Also, you may be expecting NHibernate to do too much for you. It would need to check all of the primary entity's associations for the existence of the property... but then, would you expect it to recursively go through the entire object tree looking for the property? It may be nice if it did this for you, but it seems like it would be too much of a performance hit.

Comment: Ok, i think i'm going to change QueryParameter class. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a strongly typed search class for each one my domain object class (using code generation against my domain objects for instance).

I would have an abstract class to put the `ICriteriaBuilder` logic using something very close to your current code then going recursive against any inner ICriteriaBuilder property.

I would have something like that pseudo code:

```
class SearchCriteriaBuilder
public ConstraintType constraintType
public ICriteria Build(ISearchCriteriaBuilder pSearchCriteria)
{'your code goes there'}

class AdressSearchCriteriaBuilder : SearchCriteriaBuilder
public StringSearchCriteriaBuilder street;
public IntegerSearchCriteriaBuilder number;

class PersonSearchCriteriaBuilder : SearchCriteriaBuilder
public StringSearchCriteriaBuilder name;
public AdressSearchCriteriaBuilder adress;
```

Comment: Ok i get your point. The thing is i need my system to auto-generate domain object classes from mapping files. So if someone adds some mapping files, on next start it will generate the DO classes. And adding some more auto-geneartion would make this start very slow. This is why i was hoping to write a fit-them-all piece of code. I don't know if its the best solution, but it works (i changed the queryparameter class) and for a school project that is kind of enough.

Comment: Code generation at runtime would be over kill. I meant to do the code generation at developpement time. You should recompile the binaries and include the mappings every time the database schema changes.
Have a look at db2hbm and hbm2net and modify hbm2net. It seems very posssible to modify hbm2net to generate both do and some queryparameter derived classes. You can get the source here.
http://www.felicepollano.com/2010/05/24/Hbm2netAndDb2hbmSourceCodeLocation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use an hql query like this

```
from Person p join Address a where a.Street = :street
```

And set the :street parameter with the query.

I've found that using hql is much easier than dealing with the criteria stuff, especially when you're new.  Your first instinct is to standardize your nhibernate usage, but while you're learning it, it's best to keep your code close to the nhibernate API and not write too many helper methods.

Comment: I agree. It's good to wait on creating a helper framework for yourself until you're very familiar with NHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this video at 1:57 : http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/open-source-dot-net/nhibernate-tutorial-by-ayende-rahien

Ayende (most famous nhibernate expert) tells you how to build dynamic queries using criteria api.

Watch for the foreach explanation coming at 2:04:30